# Deserialize XML To Object using Dynamic

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, deserialization, xmlserializer

Is it possible Deserialize unknown XML to object like below?

```
 var xml = @"<Students><Student><Name>Arul</Name><Mark>90</Mark></Student></Students>";

 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DynamicObject));

 dynamic students = serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: i tried it throwing exception but same logic working for Json why its not supporting with xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting XML to a dynamic C# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171525/converting-xml-to-a-dynamic-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You may want to try this.

```
string xml = @"<Students>
                <Student ID=""100"">
                    <Name>Arul</Name>
                    <Mark>90</Mark>
                </Student>
                <Student>
                    <Name>Arul2</Name>
                    <Mark>80</Mark>
                </Student>
            </Students>";

dynamic students = DynamicXml.Parse(xml);

var id = students.Student[0].ID;
var name1 = students.Student[1].Name;

foreach(var std in students.Student)
{
    Console.WriteLine(std.Mark);
}
```

---

```
public class DynamicXml : DynamicObject
{
    XElement _root;
    private DynamicXml(XElement root)
    {
        _root = root;
    }

    public static DynamicXml Parse(string xmlString)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root);
    }

    public static DynamicXml Load(string filename)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(XDocument.Load(filename).Root);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;

        var att = _root.Attribute(binder.Name);
        if (att != null)
        {
            result = att.Value;
            return true;
        }

        var nodes = _root.Elements(binder.Name);
        if (nodes.Count() > 1)
        {
            result = nodes.Select(n => n.HasElements ? (object)new DynamicXml(n) : n.Value).ToList();
            return true;
        }

        var node = _root.Element(binder.Name);
        if (node != null)
        {
            result = node.HasElements || node.HasAttributes ? (object)new DynamicXml(node) : node.Value;
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

--EDIT--

To make it work with xml namespaces, I added *RemoveNamespaces* method.

```
public class DynamicXml : DynamicObject
{
    XElement _root;
    private DynamicXml(XElement root)
    {
        _root = root;
    }

    public static DynamicXml Parse(string xmlString)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(RemoveNamespaces(XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root));
    }

    public static DynamicXml Load(string filename)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(RemoveNamespaces(XDocument.Load(filename).Root));
    }

    private static XElement RemoveNamespaces(XElement xElem)
    {
        var attrs = xElem.Attributes()
                    .Where(a => !a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                    .Select(a => new XAttribute(a.Name.LocalName, a.Value))
                    .ToList();

        if (!xElem.HasElements)
        {
            XElement xElement = new XElement(xElem.Name.LocalName, attrs);
            xElement.Value = xElem.Value;
            return xElement;
        }

        var newXElem = new XElement(xElem.Name.LocalName, xElem.Elements().Select(e => RemoveNamespaces(e)));
        newXElem.Add(attrs);
        return newXElem;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;

        var att = _root.Attribute(binder.Name);
        if (att != null)
        {
            result = att.Value;
            return true;
        }

        var nodes = _root.Elements(binder.Name);
        if (nodes.Count() > 1)
        {
            result = nodes.Select(n => n.HasElements ? (object)new DynamicXml(n) : n.Value).ToList();
            return true;
        }

        var node = _root.Element(binder.Name);
        if (node != null)
        {
            result = node.HasElements || node.HasAttributes ? (object)new DynamicXml(node) : node.Value;
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great if multiple elements are returned by fails of only a single element is returned and you are using it in a foreach!  I would suggest changing "result = new DynamicXml(node);" to "result = new List<DynamicXml>() { new DynamicXml(node) };" which will return a list with a single element.

Comment: Setting or getting attribute values is better done with TrySetIndex/TryGetIndex. So if we have an element like <person name=""rezo"" age=""18"" /> the syntax for reaching the name attribute would be person["name"].

Comment: @RezoMegrelidze But I wanted to implement it as `person.name`.

Comment: @L.B elements and attributes are not the same. So having different syntax for each one makes more sense.

Comment: @RezoMegrelidze This is my code, I wanted it that way. Feel free to write your own version according to your needs

Comment: @L.B - nicely played sir!

Comment: Bless you @L.B! Put me on the right track! Now I can sleep peacefully :-) Nice to know about DynamicObject internals!!

Comment: Impressive.
This is so useful for tacking onto an API where the response has a lot of gumph and I am just interested in 2 or 3 fields (elements).
The only thing is now that I will lie awake wondering how the hell this black magic works.
Thanks.

Comment: I needed to add `if (binder.Name == "Value") result = _root.Value;` before the final `return true` in the `DynamicXml.cs` file. In an example of XML like `<MatchTypes><MatchType>1</MatchType><MatchType>2</MatchType></MatchTypes>`, I was unable to get the Value of each MatchType. This was, of course, nested a few levels in the XML, so maybe that had something to do with it. Thanks for your wonderful submission!

Comment: This will not work if the XML document has one or more namespaces. It's necessary to change the element lookup. I have modified your answer as appropriate.

Comment: Great but I found one bug - for empty elements with attributes code returns an empty string instead of the element like here `<Student Name="Ivan" />`. I fixed this changing 39 `DynamicXml` class line to this  `result = node.HasElements || node.HasAttributes ? (object)new DynamicXml(node) : node.Value;`