# Deserialize nested xml only

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

Suppose I have xml like this:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <users>
   <user>
    <Name>User1</Name>
   </user>
   <user>
    <Name>User2</Name>
   </user>
</users>
 </B>
</A>
```

I want to deserialize only the `users` node.

Here is what I'm doing.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>), new XmlRootAttribute("users"));

StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlstring);
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    var resultda = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

But it throws an exception `<A xmlns=''>` was not expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize a portion of xml into classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083548/deserialize-a-portion-of-xml-into-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define specific serialization parameters for your User class first:

```
[XmlRoot("users")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(TypeName="user")]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And since you want to read the "users" node, you should first get that node and deserialize that node:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlstring);
XmlNode usersNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("A/B/users");

StringReader sr = new StringReader(usersNode.OuterXml);
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    List<User> resultda = (List<User>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Console.WriteLine(resultda.Count);
}
```

NOTE: It is always helpful to do it backwards if you have any problems with deserialization, meaning, just populate the object and serialize it, try/fail and finally get to your expected xml format

```
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User { Name = "User 1" });
        users.Add(new User { Name = "User 2" });
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>), new XmlRootAttribute("users")).Serialize(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), users);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "www.contoso.com", ElementName = "MyGroupName", DataType = "string", IsNullable=true)]
```

this should be in the class you re deserializing to.

---

[{"<user xmlns=''> was not expected.} Deserializing Twitter XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556874/user-xmlns-was-not-expected-deserializing-twitter-xml)