# How to Construct Object from Xml string

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, dynamicobject

How to Construct Object from Xml string using DynamicObject and how to use it.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What are you trying to achieve, what is the problem you are facing, what have you tried already. There are many possibilities: [Expando object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx), [read data from an XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172872.aspx), [xml string to object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/c-sharp-convert-xml-string-to-object), [deserialize string to object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704752/deserialize-xml-to-object-using-dynamic) and so on.

Comment: I have tried XmlDocument and I'm start making DOM Manipulation by create another element and add attribute and so, I Want to do this by Objects(Class) That Generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use XMLDocument instead DynamicObject to get the work done.