# Get Attributes of xml data (wpf c#)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem. I want to get Attributes of an Element.
The clue of my problem is, that all Elements have the same name.

How the XML-Data looks

```
<Sampels>
  <Sampel Attribute1="a" Attribute2="b" Attribute3="3" Attribute4="d" />
  <Sampel Attribute1="asdf" Attribute2="b" Attribute3="3" Attribute4="name" />
  <Sampel Attribute1="" Attribute2="" Attribute3="66" Attribute4="attri" />
  <Sampel Attribute1="" Attribute2="b" Attribute3="" Attribute4="sampelname" />
</Sampels>
```

I want to get the Attributes by knowing the right Element, specified from Attribute4.

Comment: You should take a look take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704752/deserialize-xml-to-object-using-dynamic. There are many other solutions, on Stackoverflow, you should probably search first prior to posting your question.

Comment: There they use childenotes, but I don't do and so are these both problems not equal

Comment: You can modify to pick up attributes as well, if it is not being picked up. The reason I like the solution there, is one it allows you to do things like foreach(var sample1 in sample) var attribute4 = sample1.Attribute4

Answer (score 0):

XPath will do it:

Use these includes:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

and find your attribute value (xml is your XML as string):

```
    string search = "sampelname";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XElement el = doc.XPathSelectElement(string.Format("/Sampels/Sampel[@Attribute4='{0}']", search));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
XElement xmlElement = XElement.Load("myFile.xml");


var attributes = (from e in xmlElement.Elements("Sample")
                  where e.Attribute("Attribute4").Value == "myAtribute4Value"
                  select new {
                      Attribute1 = e.Attribute("Attribute1").Value,
                      Attribute2 = e.Attribute("Attribute2").Value
                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] main)
{
        var samples = @"<Sampels>
                        <Sampel Attribute1='a' Attribute2='b' Attribute3='3' Attribute4='d' />
                        <Sampel Attribute1='asdf' Attribute2='b' Attribute3='3' Attribute4='name' />
                        <Sampel Attribute1='' Attribute2='' Attribute3='66' Attribute4='attri' />
                        <Sampel Attribute1='' Attribute2='b' Attribute3='' Attribute4='sampelname' />
                        </Sampels>";
        dynamic Sampels = DynamicXml.Parse(samples);
        foreach(var sample1 in Sampels.Sampel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sample1.Attribute4);
        }

}

// using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704752/deserialize-xml-to-object-using-dynamic

public class DynamicXml : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{
    XElement _root;
    private DynamicXml(XElement root)
    {
        _root = root;
    }

    public static DynamicXml Parse(string xmlString)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root);
    }

    public static DynamicXml Load(string filename)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(XDocument.Load(filename).Root);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(System.Dynamic.GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;

        var att = _root.Attribute(binder.Name);
        if (att != null)
        {
            result = att.Value;
            return true;
        }

        var nodes = _root.Elements(binder.Name);
        if (nodes.Count() > 1)
        {
            result = nodes.Select(n => new DynamicXml(n)).ToList();
            return true;
        }

        var node = _root.Element(binder.Name);
        if (node != null)
        {
            if (node.HasElements)
            {
                result = new DynamicXml(node);
            }
            else
            {
                result = node.Value;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```