# Trouble reading XML File with c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a XML file with the following structure:

```
    <deftable>
        <table>
            <job jobname="">
                <incond name="" />
                <outcond name="" />
            </job>
            <job jobname="">
                <incond name="" />
                <outcond name="" />
                <incond name="" />
                <outcond name="" />
            </job>
        </table>
        <table>
            <job jobname="">
                <incond name="" />
                <outcond name="" />
            </job>
            <job jobname="">
                <incond name="" />
                <outcond name="" />
                <incond name="" />
                <outcond name="" />
            </job>
        </table>
    </deftable>
```

inside the tag deftable i can have multiple tables.
in the table tag i can have multiple JOBs, and inside those I have multiple incond and outcond.

I'm trying to obtain the values for jobname, and also the value for the name attribute of incond and outcond.

I have tried several paths to accomplish this. The latest thing I tried was this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.Load(file);

       XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/deftable/table");


       int i = 1;
       foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
       {              
           Console.WriteLine(node["job"].GetAttribute("jobname") + " -- " + i);
           i++;

           XmlNodeList nodes2 =  doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/deftable/table/job");
           foreach (XmlNode item in nodes2)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(item["incond"].GetAttribute("name"));
           }


       }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?  What's the output?  What's the expected output?  Do you have any clues on what part of the code isn't working?

Comment: here's an online xpath tester, you give it a document, and an xpath: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html  From that I deduce you need two leading slashes as in `//deftable/table`

Comment: [Check this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c) for how to go about this. Doesn't look like you are digging down to the child nodes in your loop.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I managed to access the attributes i wanted using two foreach and reading ChildNodes. The link @AlwaysLearning posted was really helpful, I saw it before, but I didn't understand fully the first time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much the following snippet is useful for you, but you can try with [Linq to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx) for your case as shown below.

```
 XDocument jobsRoot = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Jobs.xml");
 var jobData= jobsRoot.Descendants()
              .Where(it => it.Name.LocalName == "job")
              .Select(job => new
               {
                  JobName = job.Attribute("jobname").Value,
                  IncondName = job.Descendants().Where(it => it.Name.LocalName == "incond").Select(inc => inc.Attribute("name").Value),
                  OutcondName = job.Descendants().Where(it => it.Name.LocalName == "outcond").Select(inc => inc.Attribute("name").Value)
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the linq to XML implementation isn't as great as XML to Dynamic

It's described on [Deserialize XML To Object using Dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704752/deserialize-xml-to-object-using-dynamic) ( since you mentioned you tried several methods). Otherwhise, the answer above would probably do.