# Creating class objects using LINQ with a highly nested XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I have xml files that I need to load and create class objects from, however, these files are formatted in, what seems to me to be a ridiculously nested way. Sadly I can't have the xml files reformatted. Here's what they look like (assume there is only one purchase entry for every customer and the name can serve as a key):

```
<root>
<start>
   <customer>
      <store store = "a">
          <customer name = "Ted Johnson">
             <product product = "shampoo">
                <price price = "10">
                </ price>
             </ product>
          </customer>
       </store>
       <store store = "b">
           <customer name = "Janet Henry">
             <product product = "soda">
                <price price = "2">
                </ price>
             </ product>
          </ customer>
       </ store>
   </ customer>

   <tax>
      <store store = "a">
          <customer name = "Ted Johnson">
             <product product = "shampoo">
                <tax tax = "1">
                  <date date = "4/4/2014">
                  </date>
                </tax>
             </ product>
          </customer>
       </store>         
      <store store = "b">
          <customer name = "Janet Henry">
             <product product = "soda">
                <tax tax = "0.2">
                  <date date = "5/5/2014">
                  </date>
                </tax>
             </ product>
          </customer>
       </store>
   </tax>
</ start>
</ root>
```

Now I need to create class objects in c#/WPF, based on this kind of monstrosity. I've been trying a few things but keep running into hurdles, and I'm worried I might end up spending a long time forcing an inefficient solution. Is there an easy way to approach this?

My goal is to create something like the following:

```
var customerPurchases = (from e in xml.Descendants(ns + "start")                         
   select new customerPurchase
   {
     name = e.Attribute("name").Value,
     store = e.Attribute("store").Value,
     product = e.Attribute("product").Value,
     price = e.Attribute("price").Value,
     tax = e.Attribute("tax").Value,
     date = e.Attribute("date").Value,  

}).ToList();
```

Any help or insight on this mess would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's an idea, pass it through a transformer to get it into a sane format. That is just ridiculous, and any code that will attempt to process it directly will be just as ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize your XML string (or file) to C# objects.
Find a sample here: https://blog.udemy.com/csharp-serialize-to-xml/

First, you must have classes associated to XML. To create classes, select your XML sample data and, in Visual Studio, go to [Edit / Paste Special / Paste XML As Classes](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11137/paste-xml-as-C-Sharp-classes-in-vs-2012.aspx).

Next, use this sample.

```
        String xData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\MyFile.xml");
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
        root dataConverted = (root)x.Deserialize(new StringReader(xData));
        // root object contains all XML data.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be very difficult (if not impossible) to find an XML deserialiser that would convert this highly custom XML into the target class.

Comment: See my sample in my answer updated... First, you must have classes associated to XML. To create classes, select your XML sample data and, in Visual Studio, go to Edit / Paste Special / Paste XML As Classes (http://bit.ly/1cE0xlm). Cool, no? I've just made this sample (I can send you a copy if you want).

Comment: You should look at the data again. It's in a format that you cannot reasonably expect any serializer to handle without _a lot_ of custom code to deal with it.

Comment: @Denis Voituron I stand corrected, this is an absolutely brilliant way to convert XML into C# classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried too much about speed, I would use LINQ to XML.

See [LINQ to XML Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb387061.aspx.).

Answer (score 0):

I would try converting the XML to a dynamic C# object. Then, the code to read the data out of the dynamic into your strongly typed POCO classes would be far more concise and a lot easier to write.

See [Converting XML to a dynamic C# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171525/converting-xml-to-a-dynamic-c-sharp-object).

Hint: If you wrap your entire parser in a try/catch, then any mismatch between the schema of the XML input, and the parsing code that uses dynamics, would be detected without bringing down the entire app.