# reading xml using xDocument - code refactoring issue

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootData>
  <PassResult>
  <FirstOne>P1</FirstOne>
  <SecondOne>P2</SecondOne>
 <IsMale>false</IsMale>
</PassResult>
<TestResult>
  <MarkOne>100</MarkOne>
  <MarkTwo>50</MarkTwo>
  <Slope>30</Slope>
</TestResult>
<ToneTestResult>
  <TotalTime>2</TotalTime>
  <CorrectPercentage>90</CorrectPercentage>
</ToneTestResult>
<QuestionnaireResult Version="1">
  <Question Id="50">
   <Answer Id="B" />
 </Question>
  <Question Id="60">
   <Answer Id="A" />
 </Question>
 </QuestionnaireResult>
</RootData>
```

I have the following code which is not at all looking a good one. Lots of repeatative link queries.
How can I refactor this code in a more structured way to fill "OutputData" object. I do not want to change it to XmlSerializer now :-(.

Sample code:

```
    // Gets the root element decendants
        var elementRootData = xDocument.Descendants("RootData");
        var xElements = elementRootData as IList<XElement> ?? elementRootData.ToList();

   // Read first leaf node "ProfileResult"
        var passResult = from xElement in xElements.Descendants("PassResult")
            select new
            {

                FirstOne = xElement.Element("FirstOne").GetValue(),
                SecondOne = xElement.Element("SecondOne").GetValue(),
                IsMale = xElement.Element("IsMale").GetValue()
            };

    // Read second leaf note
        var testResult = from xElement in xElements.Descendants("TestResult")
            select new
            {

                MarkOne = xElement.Element("MarkOne").GetValue(),
                MarkTwo = xElement.Element("MarkTwo").GetValue(),
                Slope = xElement.Element("Slope").GetValue()
            };


    // Update OutputData object
        var parseOutputData = new OutputData();

    foreach (var result in passResult)
        {
            parseOutputData.FirstOne = result.FirstOne;
            parseOutputData.SecondOne = result.SecondOne;
            parseOutputData.IsMale = result.IsMale.Equals("True");
        }

        foreach (var result in testResult)
        {
            parseOutputData.MarkOne = double.Parse(result.MarkOne);
            parseOutputData.MarkTwo = double.Parse(result.MarkTwo);
            parseOutputData.Slope = double.Parse(result.Slope);
        }
```

I have to write some more code like this to fill other elements data like ToneTestResult, QuestionnaireResult etc.
Can someone suggest with a sample code?

Best regards,

Comment: This is the same as [the question you asked 2hrs ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37659400/xml-parsing-code-refactoring-issue).  I'm not going to write the same answer twice.  This question should be deleted.