# How to get deserialized xml attribute from dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net, expandoobject

I can get the element innertext from expandoobject without any problem. I can't figure out how to get the attribute's value.

By doing `Console.WriteLine(obj.Message.Body)`, I can get the expected string inside the body element.

```
    private void TestXML()
    {
        string xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Message important=""yes"" recevied=""2019-2-12""><Body>Hi there fella!</Body></Message>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc);
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(obj.Message);

    }
```

I did a debug and and under `obj.Message` I can see 3 fields:

- @important with value "yes"
- @received with value "2019-2-12"
- Body with value "Hi there fella!"

Is there a way to retrieve the first 2 fields' values with a @ prefix? I have no idea how to deal with this @ character on dynamic objects.

Comment: why are you serializing it that way?

Comment: I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171525/converting-xml-to-a-dynamic-c-sharp-object and for me is the easiest way as I am also working with json format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To deal with special characters, such as "@" in dynamic object, you must cast it to `
(**IDictionary**). And then you can get the **recevied** attribute as bellow:

```
var received = ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj.Message)["@recevied"];
```

Comment: This worked. I can successfully get the value. What if I want to return the attribute "recevied" (just realized the spelling mistake), how am I going to do that?

Comment: You should check keys in the dictionary to make sure that there is exactly your expected attribute.

Comment: Beat me to it. I used  `List<string> keys = new List<string>(((IDictionary<string, object>)obj.Message).Keys)`  Thanks for the help.