# XML deserialization with extra types throws error

Tags: c#, deserialization, xmlserializer

I do not know the type of the XML before I deserialize it. So I'm using the overload of `XmlSerializer` with `extraTypes`. It does work for the first `type`, but it does not work for all the `extraTypes`. I'm getting the following errorMsg `"System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 40). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Bike xmlns=''> was not expected."`. Here's a dummy code of what I'm trying to do.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    private const string CarXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Car xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"></Car>";
    private const string BikeXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Bike xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"></Bike>";


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car), new[] { typeof(Bike) });

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(BikeXml))
        {
            try
            {
                var vehicle = (Vehicle)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                Console.WriteLine(vehicle.PrintMe());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

    }
}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract string PrintMe();
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override string PrintMe()
    {
        return "beep beep I'm a car!";
    }
}

public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public override string PrintMe()
    {
        return "bing bing I'm a bike!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting XML to a dynamic C# object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171525/converting-xml-to-a-dynamic-c-sharp-object)

Comment: @Progman Nope, I'm not going to use dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `extraTypes` are not meant to be used for my case. See [msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_Type___).

I solved it by getting the XmlRoot.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(BikeXml);
    var rootName = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Name;
    var rootType = Type.GetType(rootName);
    var vehicle = rootType != null ? (Vehicle) Activator.CreateInstance(rootType) : null;        
    Console.WriteLine(vehicle != null ? vehicle.PrintMe() : "Error");
}
```