# How to get XML tag names of XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am very new to c#. my project to send request in xml format to broker side which i have done it.
I am trying to handle the response which again comes in xml format. Below is the format of the response. My question is how to find the tag names that is `LocateRequest` and `LocateStatusApproved` and then all those values inside that. I tried below code but I am hardcoding the tag name which i don't want to do that.

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("LocateStatusApproved");          
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    App.logger.LogLine("inside for loop");
    string quant = node.Attributes["approvedQuantity"].Value;
    App.logger.LogLine("quant value: {0}", (quant));
}
```

Xml response file looks like below

```
<LocateResponse xmlns="http://www.omnilocate.com/StockLoan/LocateService">
  <Locates>
    <Locate>
      <LocateRequest acceptManualApproval="true" acceptPartial="true" securityId="IBM" securityIdentifierType="TICKER" market="US" requestedQuantity="10" requestorReference="98" cashOrSwap="CASH" />
      <LocateStatusApproved approvedTimeUTC="2020-12-06T18:31:18.214Z" locateId="158705132" approvedQuantity="10" rate="-108.75" rateIndicator="REBATE" />
    </Locate>
  </Locates>
  <Disclaimer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
</LocateResponse>
```

Comment: You may get some help from below links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171525/converting-xml-to-a-dynamic-c-sharp-object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704752/deserialize-xml-to-object-using-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
            Response response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("LocateResponse", Namespace = "http://www.omnilocate.com/StockLoan/LocateService")]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlArray("Locates", Namespace = "http://www.omnilocate.com/StockLoan/LocateService")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Locate", Namespace = "http://www.omnilocate.com/StockLoan/LocateService")]
        public List<Locate> Locate { get; set; }
    }
    public class Locate
    {
        public LocateRequest LocateRequest { get; set; }
        public LocateStatusApproved LocateStatusApproved { get; set; }
    }
    public class LocateRequest
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public Boolean acceptManualApproval { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public Boolean acceptPartial { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string securityId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string securityIdentifierType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string market { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int requestedQuantity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int requestorReference { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string cashOrSwap { get; set; }
    }
    public class LocateStatusApproved
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public DateTime approvedTimeUTC { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string locateId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public int approvedQuantity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal rate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string rateIndicator { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i highly appreciate your help. i am able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with XPath, and no "hard-coding" class definitions or XPath Names.  Hope this is helpful.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\t.xml"));

NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("sl", "http://www.omnilocate.com/StockLoan/LocateService");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach( XmlElement ndElement in xml.SelectNodes( "//sl:*", nsmgr)) {
    sb.Append("Element: " + ndElement.Name + "\r\n");
    foreach( XmlAttribute ndAttribute in ndElement.SelectNodes( "@*", nsmgr) ) {
        sb.Append("\tAttribute: " + ndAttribute.Name + "\r\n");
    }
}
Response.ContentType = "text";
Response.Write( sb.ToString() );
```

Produces this output.

```
Element: LocateResponse
Element: Locates
Element: Locate
Element: LocateRequest
    Attribute: acceptManualApproval
    Attribute: acceptPartial
    Attribute: securityId
    Attribute: securityIdentifierType
    Attribute: market
    Attribute: requestedQuantity
    Attribute: requestorReference
    Attribute: cashOrSwap
Element: LocateStatusApproved
    Attribute: approvedTimeUTC
    Attribute: locateId
    Attribute: approvedQuantity
    Attribute: rate
    Attribute: rateIndicator
Element: Disclaimer
    Attribute: xsi:nil
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i highly appreciate your help. i am able to solve the problem